# Connect to SQL with JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet, securityexception

I am attempting to connect to an SQL database using a JApplet. However, I get a `SecurityException`:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "162.243.229.150:3306" "connect,resolve")

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "162.243.229.150:3306" "connect,resolve")
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.unwrapExceptionToProperClassAndThrowIt(StandardSocketFactory.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at me.nrubin29.cubesorter.MySQL.setup(MySQL.java:24)
    at me.nrubin29.cubesorter.MySQL.access$100(MySQL.java:8)
    at me.nrubin29.cubesorter.MySQL$1.run(MySQL.java:35)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at me.nrubin29.cubesorter.MySQL.setup(MySQL.java:24)
    at me.nrubin29.cubesorter.MySQL.access$100(MySQL.java:8)
    at me.nrubin29.cubesorter.MySQL$1.run(MySQL.java:35)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "Thread-38" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.nrubin29.cubesorter.MySQL$1.run(MySQL.java:38)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have tried using [AccessController#doPrivileged](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged%28java.security.PrivilegedAction%29), but that didn't help. How do I grant permission to use a socket with my applet?

Comment: Are the applet and DB on the same server?  Why is the applet allowed to directly interact with the DB?  It should be forced to work through a web based API.

Comment: They are on the same server. I am allowing the direct connection because I don't know how to write a web-based API.

Comment: this is a new behavior in java 8.  Probably the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189650/new-java-security-accesscontrolexception-in-java-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsigned Applets have a number of [restrictions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) applied to them.  One of the restrictions is that they can't open network connections to hosts other than the one hosting the applet.

There are a few ways around this:

1. [Sign the applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html).  The obvious problem with this is that you need an application signing certificate.
2. Host the DB server on the same machine as the applet.
3. Write a WebStart application instead (although it probably has the same problem).

Comment: The MySQL server *is* on the same server as the web server.

Comment: @nrubin29 Are you using the same IP/address from the applet and webserver?

Comment: I tried this: `String database; if (Viewer.DESKTOP) database = "---"; else database = "localhost";`. I also added the `:3306` to the end, so don't worry there. Here's the new error: `MESSAGE: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "[fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1]:3306" "connect,resolve")`

Answer (score 2):

See these:

[java.net.SocketPermission in Applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298556/java-net-socketpermission-in-applet)

[Can signed applets connect with a different host from which they originate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608387/can-signed-applets-connect-with-a-different-host-from-which-they-originate)

If your applet is not signed, you need to make sure your applet
is loaded from the server to which it is trying to open a socket.
Then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new breakage in java 8 - it appears that sandboxed applets
are not allowed to use sockets at all.

A partial solution is to change the applet to request all-permissions.  This
changes the scary dialogs the user has to click through a little, but not much
more ominous than he already has to.

-- and of course, due to previous security calisthenics, the jars have
to be signed using a trusted certificate.